# How to deal with ERROR while using pip to install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in python using pip command as

`pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow`

and received the error message as

```
ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 requires pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 requires typed-ast<1.5,>=1.4.0; implementation_name == "cpython" and python_version < "3.8", which is not installed.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 has requirement six==1.12, but you'll have six 1.15.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: astroid 2.3.1 has requirement wrapt==1.11.*, but you'll have wrapt 1.12.1 which is incompatible.
```

So how can I manage to install them?

Answer (score 0):

do you already have a version of tensorflow installed? Assuming that you´re using the --ignore-installed option here....
This obviously keeps tensorflow from installing the required dependencies. Try without --ignore-installed (it will overwrite existing installations and hopefully update all requirements)